# How to handle multiple dependent asynchronous AJAX calls without chaining ".done()"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I'm trying to build reusable JavaScript object to perform some tasks:

```
Service = {
  getSomeID : function() {
    // Get the ID from AJAX call
    // or from cookie if AJAX fails
    // or from URL parameter if no cookie
  },

  doSomeRequest : function(url) {
    var id = this.getSomeId();

    jQuery.getJSON(url + id, function(data)) {
       // Do some really important stuff.
    });
  },

  doSomeWork : function() {
    this.doSomeRequest(this.getUrl());
  },

  getUrl : function() {
    return 'http://example.com/';
  }
};

Service.doSomeWork();
```

As you can see, `doSomeRequest()` function needs to get ID that is provided by `getSomeId()` function. The problem with this function is that callers should receive only the ID. Not the promise, because ID can be red from different places. So technically `getSomeID()` is a perfect candidate for synchronous call. Too bad because:

> As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

So the goal is to have functions that just provides real information, not deferred promises, so that these return values could be used safely in other function calls.

I want to avoid few things:

1. Avoid passing callback to `getSomeId()` function that
   would be used to invoke another `jQuery.getJSON()` because it would
   mean that I'd also have to pass the url. And that turns simple
   `getSomeId()` function into
   `getSomeIdThenInvokeCallbackWithParameter(callback, parameter)` function which I don't want because `getSomeId()` is usable in different contexts and not all of them involve making AJAX calls.
2. Avoid chaining `.done().done().done()` multiple times as
   this defeats the purpose of having separate functions for separate
   pieces of logic and does not let me reuse code.

Comment: `getSomeID()` could return a deferred object that you resolved as you wish and then using `this.getSomeId().done(function(id){jQuery.getJSON(url + id, function(data)) {
       // Do some really important stuff.
    });});`

Comment: I meant e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/49o98k8c/

Comment: @A.Wolff I won't say that I like this but if you turn your JS fiddle into an answer I think I'll accept it. Although it's really annoying that synchronous calls are deprecated. Having to manage long chains of `.done().done().done()` is really annoying and I don't see a reason why nested AJAX calls couldn't be synchronous.

Comment: Thank you everybody, that will make me write my next projects in a lot better way.